# sqlAlchemy Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

i am using aiogram, sqlalchemy and mysql for tg bot. So it runs 7/24.

I'm getting an error after a few hours of db inactivity. I googled and found that it is the mysql timeout (8 hours) that disconnects the connection. To get around this error, I added all these parameters in order:

`engine = create_engine(url, pool_timeout=7, pool_recycle=60, pool_pre_ping=True, isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT")`

But none of them helped.

First the connection is reset and gives an error
`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')`
then
`exception=PendingRollbackError("Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back. Please rollback() fully before proceeding")`

Reproduce error:

1. run script
2. is has 5 seconds timeout. Press enter for sending query.
3. if wait 5 seconds then press enter again it will gives Lost connection error.
4. press enter again, it will give PendingRollbackError error.

```
import traceback
from asyncio import get_event_loop

# Initialize the bot and dispatcher
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, URL, text
from sqlalchemy.exc import OperationalError, PendingRollbackError
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, declarative_base, scoped_session

from config import DB_DRIVER_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_HOST, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE

loop = get_event_loop()

Base = declarative_base()

url = URL.create(
    drivername=DB_DRIVER_NAME,
    username=DB_USERNAME,
    host=DB_HOST,
    password=DB_PASSWORD,
    database=DB_DATABASE
)

engine = create_engine(url, pool_recycle=3, pool_pre_ping=True, isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT")

connection = engine.connect()

connection.execute(text("SET wait_timeout=5"))  # Short timeout for testing pool_recycle.
connection.execute(text("SELECT 1"))

print("Create new session")
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
session = Session()


def run():
    input("Press enter for sending SELECT 1 query")
    print("sql execution start")
    connection.execute(text("SELECT 1"))  # This throws the error.
    connection.commit()
    print("sql commit end")
    run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        run()
    except OperationalError or PendingRollbackError:
        print("OperationalError PendingRollbackError manual rollback")
        traceback.print_exc()
        session.rollback()
        session.close()
        run()
```

Comment: The query runs into a timeout, you should test the query in workbench and try to optimize it, or increase the timeous

Comment: There are only 4 rows in the table and it is a very simple query. It simply searches by user_id, which is indexed.

Comment: Llost Connections are caused , when the query takes too long, this can also happening with locks, see first into the MySQL error log , the restart the server

Comment: slow query logs empty. it has 2 seconds limit. But it is about connection = engine.connect(). connection should be recreated after pool_recycle time. but id does not.

Comment: i have added small script for reproduce error.

Comment: I am more interested in the error log, the slow error log wouldn't be triggered the lock coul be interesting

Comment: Why `connection.commit()`? There is no transaction in your code.

Comment: Cross-posted and answered on GitHub [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/10328).